# Python: Assign missing value to rows in one column if any row is missing value in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe where column 'Score' is calculated from values in other columns. I would need to have missing value in Score column if any of other columns has missing value for that row.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Score': [71, 63, 23],
                   'Factor_1': [nan, '15', '23'],
                   'Factor_2': ['12', nan, '45'],
                   'Factor_3': ['3', '5', '7']})
```

Expected values for column Score: nan, nan, 23 (because Factor 1 is missing in 1st row and Factor 2 is missing in 2nd row). So, I should replace existing values with NAs.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for `Factor` column, test if missing values by  [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) for at least one value per row by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and set `NaN` by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.filter(like='Factor').isna().any(axis=1), 'Score'] = np.nan
```

Or use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Score'] = df['Score'].mask(df.filter(like='Factor').isna().any(axis=1))
```

If need explicit columns names:

```
cols = ['Factor_1', 'Factor_2', 'Factor_3']
df.loc[df[cols].isna().any(axis=1), 'Score'] = np.nan
```

---

```
df['Score'] = df['Score'].mask(df[cols].isna().any(axis=1))
```

---

```
print (df)
   Score Factor_1 Factor_2 Factor_3
0    NaN      NaN       12        3
1    NaN       15      NaN        5
2   23.0       23       45        7
```

Comment: Sorry, totally forgot to mention that Factor 1,2,3 are not the only other columns in df, so I would need to explicitly say which column to look for assigning NA values.. sorry once again for missing to recognise

Comment: @Beginnerinthehouse - added to solution.